# In a DB2 SQL query, how can you replace leading zeroes in a string with spaces to maintain a fixed length?

Tags: sql, db2

```
1                                    
------------------
YYY100.00XXX
YYY025.00XXX
YYY005.00XXX
```

^ The above selection results from a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT CAST(STRING1 AS CHAR(3)) ||
       CAST(DECIMAL1 AS CHAR(6)) ||
       CAST(STRING2 AS CHAR(3))
FROM TABLE;
```

My problem is the "025.00" and "005.00" - I need it to be " 25.00" and "  5.00" respectively - the leading zero needs to be replaced with a space and not removed so that the query looks like this:

```
1                                    
------------------
YYY100.00XXX
YYY 25.00XXX
YYY  5.00XXX
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

*edit: I'm on DB2 v8.2.2*

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the conversion to `char(6)`.  To do what you want, use `varchar()` and `lpad()`:

```
SELECT CAST(STRING1 AS CHAR(3)) ||
       LPAD(CAST(DECIMAL1 AS VARCHAR(6)), 6, ' ') ||
       CAST(STRING2 AS CHAR(3))
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: Is LPAD available on my version of DB2? I'm on v8.2.2 (sorry for not mentioning that on my opening post)